# Change devise sign up path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, sign

#### I need redirect user to separate page except root page

Here is my registrations controller (overriding `after_sign_up_path_for` method):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  
  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      redirect_to xxxx_path
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the redirection, in the method just write the `foo_path` instead of `redirect_to foo_path`

Your code should be as follows
**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    foo_path
  end
end
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Ya oss, it does't have to be in the application_controller, the error is that the method should return a `path` not `redirect_to path`